# Spree commerce spree taxonomies error

Tags: ruby, spree

I'm trying to run my spree commerce project (2.0), but when I excute the command
`rails server`, this message is displayed

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Spree/home#index

> Showing
>   /home/iron/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/spree_frontend-2.0.1/app/views/spree/shared/_taxonomies.html.erb
>   where line #2 raised:
>
> Could not find table 'spree_taxonomies' Extracted source (around line #2):

```
1: <nav id="taxonomies" class="sidebar-item" data-hook>
2:   <% get_taxonomies.each do |taxonomy| %>
3:     <h6 class='taxonomy-root'><%= Spree.t(:shop_by_taxonomy, :taxonomy => taxonomy.name) %></h6>
4:     <%= taxons_tree(taxonomy.root, @taxon, Spree::Config[:max_level_in_taxons_menu] || 1) %>
5:   <% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error occurs because database table `spree_taxonomies` doesn't exist.
You should run `rake db:migrate` in order to create database and tables.

Answer (score 0):

Dont forget to be doing it on the production environment
rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production
rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production

Answer (score 0):

Looks like spree_taxonomies table is missing. You need to 
**run rake db:migrate**

On Production - **RAILS_ENV=production rake db:migrate**

Answer (score 0):

All the above answers should solve the problem. 
I would just like to note there is a best practice when developing applications in rails.

Add a `bin/setup` file which does all the grunt work for you.
This solves the problem of remembering all the tasks you have to do when starting on a project.

Just execute `bin/setup` and your done.

Source:
http://robots.thoughtbot.com/bin-setup